# need help in string Concatenate in bash

Tags: unix

I have two files `System_Names` & `system_appendix_names` . I want to Concatenate each & every line of one file to other file`s line and save output to other file.

```
root@bt:~/kevin/new# cat system_appendix_names 
adm
-adm
_adm

root@bt:~/kevin/new#cat System_Names 
help
not
now
give
you
haha
what
where
if
```

I made following script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
cat System_Names | while read line1
 do 
    cat system_appendix_names | while read line2
    do 
        out="${line1}${line2}"
        echo "$out" >> 1.txt

     done

done
```

Output of script:

```
root@bt:~/kevin/new# cat 1.txt 
helpadm
help-adm
help_adm
notadm
not-adm
not_adm
nowadm
now-adm
now_adm
giveadm
give-adm
give_adm
youadm
you-adm
you_adm
hahaadm
haha-adm
haha_adm
whatadm
what-adm
what_adm
whereadm
where-adm
where_adm
ifadm
if-adm
if_adm
```

Above script work for small amount of lines in file.Actually i have files which have more lines. SO i tried it, but can not  Concatenate  string line by line.

Comment: when i tried with large amount of lines in file , it`s not Concatenate.It takes lin1 word & then other`s file line 1 word is placed in new line.for example it print help which is line 1 of one file & then print adm which is line1 of other file, but adm is in new line. not Concatenate .

Comment: @user1454 It seems that your input files have `CR+LF` line endings.  Try running `dos2unix` on the input files before executing your script.